# Gitlab Secret Variable >>> Spring Boot application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I reference a gitlab secret variable in an application.yml? I assume it is only accessable within gitlab-ci.yml context and has to be moved from there into the Docker image as a VM parameter somehow?

In case it matters, I am deploying in a Rancher environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `export` it or pass as a command line parameter to you `CI` script. Like:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
deploy-app:
  stage: deploy
  image: whatever
  script:
    - export MY_SECRET
    - ...
```

**or**

```
deploy-app:
  stage: deploy
  image: whatever
  script:
    - docker run -it -e PASSWORD=$MY_SECRET whatever ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have tried `- export MY_SECRET` but the rancher Job still terminates because a bean cannot be initialized without the variable. Is it possible that I am setting the secret variable in the wrong project?

The Microservice project builds, not runs (I see `docker run` in your reply) the docker-image. It is another project that composes a rancher stack that pulls the docker image and then runs it. Or can a variable be injected both at build and at run-time?

Comment: try `-echo $MY_SECRET` and then `export NEW_SECRET=$MY_SECRET`. First statement will show if you have initialized it, the second will export it to the script under different name

Comment: are you sure I need the $-prefix? in the gitlab-GUI the variable has no $

Comment: As @grapes said you need $ prefix, more about variables in gitlab-ci you can find [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I can see in the Gitlab-CI-Pipeline the echo-output with the variable's value. But when the rancher-composing project iniitalizes the previously built docker-image, I still get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'NEW_SECRET' in value "${NEW_SECRET}"` (in Rancher-Runner's log)

Comment: Post your CI script for better understanding

Comment: Ok it works now. The problem was as I expected to export the variable in the project that runs the docker image, not the one that builds it